# Copying original attributes from DGN file using ArcGIS Data Interoperability Quick Import?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, data-interoperability

I am new to Data Interoperability extension and I wanted to ask you why "Quick Import" tool doesn't allow me to copy the original attributes from my DGN file.

When I check the results in geodatabase I is some new columns named: IDGS Color, IDGS Class etc.

Why I can't copy those originals? Do I need to check some options in the setting?

Comment: Are you saying that attribute names are not preserved or that you are losing attribute values?

Comment: Attributes names are not preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [ArcGIS 10 Documentation for Quick Import](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001600000005000000.htm) it says:

"This tool creates a default output schema for the geodatabase that is created. If the output requires schema changes, then the Spatial ETL Tool should be used."

I've not used the Spatial ETL Tool but according to its [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004m0000000m000000.htm) it opens the FME Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

By attributes I'm assuming you mean tags, so yes, a Quick Import doesn't handle tags in that way.

However, when you create a Spatial ETL tool, simply click the parameters button and choose "group by attribute schema". This should expose and enable these attributes in the workspace.